# Clustering : two different values for the within sum of square

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm doing a clustering analysis and I have two issues :

1. I found two different values for the  within sum of square with these 2 methods :

**1/ First method founded here** : http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/cluster.html

```
set.seed(180)
wss <- (nrow(mydata)-1)*sum(apply(mydata,2,var)) 

for (i in 1:8)
wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(mydata, 
     centers=i)$withinss)

wss
[1] 2244832.0 1707497.8 1514193.9 1131349.7  990028.8  698772.0  683106.4  522783.8
```

**2/ Second method**

```
set.seed(180)    
fit <- kmeans(mydata, 5) 

fit$tot.withinss
[1] 857443.8
```

As you can see 990 028 !=857 443 even though  I used "set.seed"

Is there a mistake in the formula of the Statmethods website ?

**Lastly**, sometimes the wss raise with the number of cluster. Is it ok or it's impossible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use `set.seed` but you also do a lot with the random number generator before getting to kmeans(data, 5) in your first example.  You are likely getting a different clustering solution.  If you just look at `sum(fit$withinss)` it should match `fit$tot.withinss` for a given clustering solution.  There is some randomness involved though so if you want the same thing you need to make sure you set the seed  properly.

Comment: I was going to phrase it: the seeds are only the same for the first iteration of the for loop and the second methods.

Comment: So it's impossible to use set.seed on a vector ? It will be the same only for the first element ?
Edit : thanks Joran

Comment: About the raising of the wss, can you confirm it's not possible if the seed is the same ?

Comment: If a put the set.seed statement in the loop like this, is it ok ? 

`for (i in 1:8) set.seed(180)   
wss[i] <- sum(kmeans(mydata, 
     centers=i)$withinss)`

Answer (score 0):

By setting the initial `centers` you effectively provide a manual seed.

k-means only uses the random seed during initial generation of the centers.

So in fact, you provide two different initializations, and as such you shouldn't be surprised to get different results. K-means only finds local optima.